# AlertControl doesn't show

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a strange problem with devexpress AlertControl. I create an alertu using this code

```
 AlertInfo alertInfo = new AlertInfo(caption, text);
    AlertControl control = new AlertControl();
    control.FormLocation = AlertFormLocation.BottomRight;
    control.Show(null,alertInfo);
```

this code is placed in backgroundWorker_DoWork function and it is supposed to display alerts from time to time. The problem is that alerts are not shown. I can see that show method is invoked however alerts are not shown. 
Acording to documentation is I pass null as a parametr of Show function , notification should be shown on main monitor. 
What can I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 4):

Considering you're using a worker, I guess it's a thread problem. Try wrapping your code inside an `Action` object:

```
Action action = () =>
{
    AlertControl control = new AlertControl();
    control.FormLocation = AlertFormLocation.BottomRight;
    control.Show(this, alertInfo); // "this" being a Form
};

this.Invoke(action);
```

I use a similar code inside a form with good results and once did a similar code using an `AlertControl` too.

Answer (score 1):

Your AlertControl need a Parent Control.

```
AlertControl control = new AlertControl();
control.FormLocation = AlertFormLocation.BottomRight;
control.Show(MyForm,alertInfo); //replace null with a Form/Control instance
```

You call the Show method with a null paramater - where you should have use an instance of a Form/Control

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about the devexpress controls, but maybe you have to show the alert from the main thread via invoke methode?

Comment: I can't use invoke method because I don't show this from a form - the class I invoke it from isn't control or form

Comment: you cannot use the visual control from a background thread.  This won't work.

Comment: @platon so how can I achieve my goal ? any ideas?

Comment: there should be a form.  If your application is a WindowsForms application, and it is, there should be the main form in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Alerter;

// Create a regular custom button.
AlertButton btn1 = new AlertButton(Image.FromFile(@"c:\folder-16x16.png"));
btn1.Hint = "Open file";
btn1.Name = "buttonOpen";
// Create a check custom button.
AlertButton btn2 = new AlertButton(Image.FromFile(@"c:\clock-16x16.png"));
btn2.Style = AlertButtonStyle.CheckButton;
btn2.Down = true;
btn2.Hint = "Alert On";
btn2.Name = "buttonAlert";
// Add buttons to the AlertControl and subscribe to the events to process button clicks
alertControl1.Buttons.Add(btn1);
alertControl1.Buttons.Add(btn2);
alertControl1.ButtonClick += new AlertButtonClickEventHandler(alertControl1_ButtonClick);
alertControl1.ButtonDownChanged += 
    new AlertButtonDownChangedEventHandler(alertControl1_ButtonDownChanged);

// Show a sample alert window.
AlertInfo info = new AlertInfo("New Window", "Text");
alertControl1.Show(this, info);

void alertControl1_ButtonDownChanged(object sender, 
AlertButtonDownChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ButtonName == "buttonOpen") {
        //...
    }
}

void alertControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, AlertButtonClickEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ButtonName == "buttonAlert") {
        //...
    }
}
```

ref:https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsAlerterAlertControltopic